# How to use index and get rid of React Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Hello I'm facing this error, question is how to propertly pass index in this component?

Error:

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:117 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Here is the component's code fragment:

```
                            {calculatorScreenshots.map((imgUrl: any, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <Zoom>
                                        {props.projectName == 'Calculator' && (
                                            <CardMedia
                                                key={index}
                                                component="img"
                                                height="200"
                                                alt="project picture"
                                                image={imgUrl}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    </Zoom>
                                );
                            })}
```

Comment: You need to pass key property to Zoom component

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like it was easy fix :D

Comment: Why not `imgUrl: String`?

Answer (score 2):

The top-level `<Zoom>` component needs a `key` attribute as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should be placing the key prop at the **first element**

```
                        {calculatorScreenshots.map((imgUrl: any, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Zoom key={index}>
                                    {props.projectName == 'Calculator' && (
                                        <CardMedia
                                  
                                            component="img"
                                            height="200"
                                            alt="project picture"
                                            image={imgUrl}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                </Zoom>
                            );
                        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `key` props to the element you rendering with `map()`.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

In your case, you forgot to add a `key={imgUrl}` to `<Zoom></Zoom>` element whereas it's the first element rendered with `map()`

To turn off this warning, here the solution:

```
{calculatorScreenshots.map((imgUrl: String, index) => {
    return (
        <Zoom key={imageUrl}>
            {props.projectName == 'Calculator' && (
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  height="200"
                  alt="project picture"
                  image={imgUrl}
                />
             )}
       </Zoom>
   )})}
```

You were almost there, you simply put the `key` props for the second mapped element, not for the first one `<Zoom></Zoom>`.

Happy coding

---

Some good pieces of information :

> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys

> When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.

You can find more information here :

[List and Keys with React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

[Index as a key is an anti-pattern by Robin Pokorny](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

[Why keys are necessary for React?](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children)

Answer (score 0):

You should write `key` in `<Zoom />` component rather than in `<CardMedia />` like this

`<Zoom key={index} />`

Note: Always write key to first item component/element you are rendering here it is `<Zoom />`.